# resignFirstResponder with UIControlEventEditingChanged causes app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I set UITextFieldDelegate in my .h and in my .m have `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myPhoneNumber;`

In my viewDidLoad method I have

```
[self.myPhoneNumber setDelegate:self];

[self.myPhoneNumber addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(editingChanged:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

My editingChanged: method listens to make sure the text input is >9 characters and then enables a button

```
- (IBAction)editingChanged:(id)sender {
    if ([self.myPhoneNumber.text length] <= 9) {
        self.myButton.enabled = NO;
    }
    else {
        self.myButton.enabled = YES;
    }
}
```

This works exactly how I want it to but when I press return on the keyboard to hide it this crashes the app with the error:

```
2014-07-15 08:08:27.089 sample-chat[47702:90b] -[MyViewController editingChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ba7420
2014-07-15 08:08:27.093 sample-chat[47702:90b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyViewController editingChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ba7420'
```

My method for returning the keyboard is as follows

```
 -(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified the return type of `editingChanged:` as `IBAction`. This is only required for linking up this method in Interface Builder, which would be redundant since you manually added the `UIControlEventEditingChanged` listener in `viewDidLoad`.

Either use

```
- (void)editingChanged:(id)sender
```

OR

use the method as is, but link it to the `UIControlEventEditingChanged` in Interface Builder.

Comment: thanks! I changed it to void and it work perfectly. i'm a newb programmer and basic stuff like this always sidetracks me, I hope to develop a better eye for detail with more practice.

Comment: Better to use text field delegate shouldChangeCharactersInRange instead of this custom selector with specified control event

Answer (score 0):

Try this Way @mostly

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger length = editingTextField.text.length - range.length + string.length;
    if (length > 0) {
        yourButton.enabled = YES;
    } else { 
        yourButton.enabled = NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

oky u can also try do this by using `NSNotificationCenter`, for example u want t check each character that entered to text field then u can try this

for example

```
//add the observer
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(editingChanged:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

//remove the observer
 - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)editingChanged:(id)sender
{
   if ([self.myPhoneNumber.text length] <= 9) {
      self.myButton.enabled = NO;
   }
   else {
      self.myButton.enabled = YES;
  }
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to use a custom selector like you done. It is better to use the text field delegate methods to manage this.

Set the delegate `[self.myPhoneNumber setDelegate:self];`
And implement the delegate methods like :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    self.myButton.enabled = NO;
    if (textField == _myPhoneNumber)
    {
        if (textField.text.length > 9)
        {
            self.myButton.enabled = YES;
        }
    }
}


-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    return YES;
}
```